# vueHtml2Pdf renders blank page (Nuxt)

Tags: javascript, vue.js, pdf, nuxt.js

I am using [vueHtml2Pdf](https://github.com/kempsteven/vue-html2pdf) to generate my page to pdf, but when I wrap my content inside VueHtml2pdf tag nothing renders on my page, but it downloads when I click the download button. (Nuxt)

```js
  methods: {
    downloadPDF() {
      this.$refs.html2Pdf.generatePdf()
    },
  },
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/vue/2.5.17/vue.js"></script>



        <ArticleActions @download="downloadPDF()" />
    

    <client-only>
      <vue-html2pdf
        ref="html2Pdf"
        :show-layout="false"
        :enable-download="true"
        :pdf-quality="2"
        :manual-pagination="true"
        pdf-content-width="100%"
        :html-to-pdf-options="htmlToPdfOptions"
      >
        <section slot="pdf-content">
      <!-- content -->
          <div
            v-interpolation="{ newWindow: true }"
            class="articleContent__content"
            v-html="article.content"
          ></div>
      <!-- /content -->
        </section>
      </vue-html2pdf>
    </client-only>
```

Comment: What if you try `@click="downloadPDF"`?

Comment: Also, do you see an error in either your console or the vue devtools? They do have a working [demo example](https://github.com/kempsteven/vue-html2pdf-demo/blob/master/src/App.vue), it may be worth giving it a try.

Comment: @kissu no console error, my content is not displaying on the page, however when I click "Download pdf" it's downloads the right content>

Answer (score 2):

I have a working solution for Nuxtv3 (with server-side rendering). After trying a bunch of different vue-specific packages, including `vue-html2pdf`, I realized that most of them have been written for Vue2.

Instead, I chose to use [`html2pdf`](https://www.npmjs.com/package/html2pdf.js/v/0.9.0) directly.

Upon directly importing `html2pdf` in the component where I need to add the functionality for converting html to pdf, Nuxt throws the following error: `ReferenceError: self is not defined`. This essentially happens because the line where the library is being imported runs on the server side as well and when it is imported, it tries to access a variable that isn't defined on the server side.

My solution was to create a custom plugin that runs only on the client side. It is very simple to do this in Nuxtv3 by just ending the filename with `.client.ts` as opposed to just `.ts`. Here is what `plugins/html2pdf.client.ts` looks like:

```js
import html2pdf from 'html2pdf.js'

export default defineNuxtPlugin(() => {
  // had to make a plugin because directly importing html2pdf.js in the component
  // where I need to use it was causing an error as the import would run on the server
  // side and html2pdf.js is a client-side-only library. This plugin runs on the
  // client side only (due to the .client extension) so it works fine.
  return {
    provide: {
      html2pdf: (element, options) => {
        return html2pdf(element, options)
      }
    }
  }
})
```

Now, I can safely use it in my component as:

```js
const { $html2pdf } = useNuxtApp()

function downloadPDF() {
  if (document) {
    const element = document.getElementById('html2pdf')

    // clone the element: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60557116/html2pdf-wont-print-hidden-div-after-unhiding-it/60558415#60558415
    const clonedElement = element.cloneNode(true) as HTMLElement
    clonedElement.classList.remove('hidden')
    clonedElement.classList.add('block')
    // need to append to the document, otherwise the downloading doesn't start
    document.body.appendChild(clonedElement)

    // https://www.npmjs.com/package/html2pdf.js/v/0.9.0#options
    $html2pdf(clonedElement, {
      filename: 'filename.pdf',
      image: { type: 'png' },
      enableLinks: true
    })
    clonedElement.remove()
  }  
}
```

Basic usage of `html2pdf`: https://www.npmjs.com/package/html2pdf.js/v/0.9.0#usage

Configuration for `html2pdf`: https://www.npmjs.com/package/html2pdf.js/v/0.9.0#options

Answer (score 0):

If someone looking for how to use html2pdf in nuxt 2.

1. install html2pdf.js using npm or yarn
2. create html-to-pdf.js file in nuxt plugin directory with below code

```
import html2pdf from 'html2pdf.js'

export default (context, inject) => {
  inject('html2pdf', html2pdf)
}
```

3. Then add plugin to nuxt.config.js

```
 plugins: [
      '@/plugins/axios',
      ......
      { src: '@/plugins/html-to-pdf', mode: 'client' },
    ],
```

4. How to use , example in your component menthod

```
  methods: {
    export() {
      this.$html2pdf(this.$refs.document, {
        margin: 1,
        filename: 'file-name.pdf',
        image: { type: 'jpeg', quality: 0.98 },
        html2canvas: {
          scale: 1,
          dpi: 192,
          letterRendering: true,
          ignoreElements: true,
        },
        jsPDF: { unit: 'pt', format: 'a2', orientation: 'portrait' },
      })
    },
```